# Trying to replace certain characters with other characters in a string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I am learning TypeScript and for this particular problem, I am trying to replace certain characters in a string with another character. So if there is an A, I want to replace it with a T.  If there is a T, I want to replace it with an A. If there is a C, I want to replace it with a G. If there is a G, I want to replace it with a C.

The outputs would be something like this:

```
dnaStrand("ATTGC") // return "TAACG"

dnaStrand("GTAT") // return "CATA"
```

Below is my code. I decided to add an if/else statement to the static method by incorporating the include and replace method for strings.  Unfortunately, it is not working.  The errors I am getting seem to be syntax related.  As you can see below.  Can somebody help?

```
export class Kata {
  static dnaStrand(dna: string) {
    if(dna.includes('A')){
      dna.replace('A', 'T')
    } else if (dna.includes('T')){
      dna.replace('T', 'A'){
        else if (dna.includes('C')){
          dna.replace('C', 'G')
        }else(dna.includes('G')){
          dna.replace('G', 'C')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Kata.dnaStrand("ATTGC")
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need a `{` after `dna.replace('T', 'A'){`, you need a `;`. Every `if(...)` and `else(...)` should have an opening curly bracket `{` and a closing curly bracket `}` (or both can be omitted if you only have one line under them).

Comment: Also, `.replace()` does not change `dna` in-place, it produces a new modified string. I'm guessing you'll want to return the result as well at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced bracket which is invalid syntax:

```
dna.replace('T', 'A'){
```

But even fixing that, your current approach won't work because it'll only replace one character. If you tried to fix it by calling the method multiple times, you'd just toggle that one character.

Use a regular expression with a callback and an object instead:

```
const chars = {
  A: 'T',
  T: 'A',
  C: 'G',
  G: 'C',
};
const dnaStrand = (dna: string) => dna.replace(/./g, char => chars[char]);
```